# How do I use the -> (arrow) operator?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have a `Postgresql` database and I'm using in my application `JOOQ`. I need to implement a query where I need the operator `->`. I use the operator for the `select` and the for the `left join`. Take a look below:

```
select coalesce(u.name, data->'username') as username, user_location, user_time
   from log
   left join users u on (data->'username') is not null and (data->'username') = u.username 
where ((data->'code') is null or (data->'code') <> 'no')
```

What is the best way to implement this case? I found this [link](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/#N3FB06) but I think is to complex just to implement that, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something is not supported (yet) in jOOQ, you can always resort to using the [plain SQL API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/). In your case, you could write a utility like:

```java
public static Field<String> jsonAttr(Field<?> json, String attrName) {
    return DSL.field("{0}->{1}", String.class, json, DSL.inline(attrName));
}
```

Note that [`DSL.inline()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline-java.lang.String-) will escape your string literal to [prevent SQL injection](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/05/prevent-sql-injection-with-sql-builders-like-jooq/). Always be careful of this possibility with the plain SQL API

You can now use the above as such:

```java
// Assuming this static import
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

// Aliasing
Users u = USERS.as("u");

// You didn't qualify all your columns, so I'm assuming DATA is in LOG
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(
        coalesce(u.NAME, jsonAttr(LOG.DATA, "username")).as("username"),
        u.USER_LOCATION,
        u.USER_TIME)
   .from(LOG)
   .leftJoin(u)
       .on(jsonAttr(LOG.DATA, "username").isNotNull())
       .and(jsonAttr(LOG.DATA, "username").eq(u.USERNAME))
   .where(jsonAttr(LOG.DATA, "code").isNull())
   .or(jsonAttr(LOG.DATA, "code").ne("no"))
   .fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by JOOQ. Check https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3491

**EDIT:**
The alternatives would be to use JOOQ simply as query executor: 
check the example here https://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-sql-executor/

or retrieve the json and do the parson on Java

Comment: I know is not supported. is the reason I'm asking to get a solution or see how the people resolve the same problem I'm having. Probably a custom jooq type or  a different way to work with `hstore`

Comment: It's generally a good idea to pull out the relevant quotes/sections from a link in your answer. Firstly so it doesn't require someone to click through. Secondly, in case the link goes dead. Do that and I'll give you an upvote :)